# How can i get Auto Suggestion Bulb in intellji when hover over the widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, ide, widget, search-suggestion

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA (Educational Version 2019.3) IDE for the flutter Development. A few days before I got widget suggestions like this While to hover over the widget [image: See the bulb icon, I got this for suggestion widget]
     Now Today I can't find this suggestion bulb, How can I enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `Alt + Enter`. I Found this answer in this medium [post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-ide-shortcuts-for-faster-development-2ef45c51085b).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Show  intention bulb` under `Settings > Editor > General > Appearance`

Comment: I enabled all the things in Appearance in `Settings > Editor > General > Appearance` but  no difference